# How to take a dictionary and send a JSON Response

Tags: python, django, json, dictionary

I have the following function,

```
def facebooktest(request):
    fb_value = ast.literal_eval(request.body)
    fb_foodies = Foodie.objects.filter(facebook_id__in = fb_value.values())
    for fb_foodie in fb_foodies:
        state = request.user.relationships.following().filter(username = fb_foodie.user.username).exists()
        userData = {
            'fbid': fb_foodie.facebook_id,
            'followState': int(state),
                }
```

Basically I am checking to see which of the user's facebook friends are on my django app. If they are, return the followState. The followState basically returns a 1 or a 0. 1 if the user is already following them on my Django app and 0 if they are not following their facebook friend on my Django app.

I would like to return back a json type dictionary to that user that looks like this:

```
[{fbid:222222222222, followState: 0}, {fbid:111111111111, followState: 1}, {fbid:435433434534, followState:1}]
```

## EDIT

I have the dictionary structure but I just want to return it like the structure above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def facebooktest(request):
    fb_value = ast.literal_eval(request.body)
    fb_foodies = Foodie.objects.filter(facebook_id__in = fb_value.values())
    response = []
    for fb_foodie in fb_foodies:
        state = request.user.relationships.following().filter(username = fb_foodie.user.username).exists()
        userData = {
            'fbid': fb_foodie.facebook_id,
            'followState': int(state),
                }
        response.append(userData)
    return json.dumps(response)
```

Comment: This is not a view as it does not return an HttpResponse, but it returns a JSON string with the structure you asked for.

Comment: Thank you, we figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in the django.forms.models package for that: model_to_dict

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

model_to_dict(your_model, fields=[], exclude=[])
```

From the help:

```
model_to_dict(instance, fields=None, exclude=None)
    Returns a dict containing the data in ``instance`` suitable for passing as
    a Form's ``initial`` keyword argument.

    ``fields`` is an optional list of field names. If provided, only the named
    fields will be included in the returned dict.

    ``exclude`` is an optional list of field names. If provided, the named
    fields will be excluded from the returned dict, even if they are listed in
    the ``fields`` argument.
```

Comment: I edited my question, please do take a look! I think I may have not been clear :)

Comment: My answer is quite irrelevant indeed!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this:

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='application/json')
```

where 'response_dict' would be your dictionary.